# Code deployment in different webapps from one Bitbucket at once

Tags: azure, web-applications, bitbucket, autoscaling

I am new to Azure and I am setting up Umbraco Webapp. My scenario is I have two datacenters east and southeast and in each datacenter I have Umbraco webapp with MS SQL.

My questions are:
How to push build to webapps ? I m doing it through Bitbucket.. But it is deploying only to east datacenter webapp. I want to know is it possible to push code from bit bucket to both datacenter at one time. My both datacenters are under traffic manager. If its not possible , what is the best practice to sync content to both webapps at once?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you currently using BitBucket to push the build?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have two Azure Web Apps and you are using BitBucket to deploy.

In both of your Web Apps,

1. Setup deployment from source control.
2. Choose BitBucket.

When you push to BitBucket, it will automatically deploy to both. Is there any reason why this will not work?

[image]

I am assuming you have setup Traffic Manager [like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2014/03/18/using-windows-azure-traffic-manager-with-waws.aspx).